# Why can't I run data queries on the Math Site?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

Maybe this question has already been asked, but I can't seem to find Math.SE on [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/). On other sites there have been some useful queries run, and I was hoping to look into the Math site, but I cannot find it in the choices.

Anybody know why?

Comment: +1: I've been wondering the same thing.

Comment: (Besides math.SE, cooking.SE isn't on SEDE either.)

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/710/can-we-get-database-dumps

Comment: Even after the recent data migration (of Dec 21 2010), it seems to be missing.

Comment: @Jeff: math.SE and cooking.SE are **still** not on SEDE.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry about that ... I missed maths ... it should be working now.

Comment: Confirmed.. :-)

Comment: Dear Sam, Thanks! I am also pleased to see the MSE database dumps.

Comment: ok thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find it right now, but I remember reading somewhere (maybe on Jeff's blog, maybe on meta.SO) that it takes a couple of cycles before a new SE site gets in to the database dump, and it only dates from when it went public.  Since the database is only updated each month, it may be that math.SE just hasn't been public long enough to get in yet.  Also, reading the latest articles, I see that they're mucking around with the architecture underneath the data dumps so that might mean it takes them a bit longer to put the new sites in.

Comment: Hmm, maybe. But I am pretty sure Math.SE is older than Photo.SE.

Comment: @BBischof: I decided to check, and it seems like Photo.SE is likely older. The first question on Photo.SE is dated July 15, while the first question on Math.SE is Jul 20!

Comment: Although, seems like cstheory is now there, which is definitely younger than math.se.